# line_before does not work in blank PS file

Tags: rexx

I am able to use below code to insert a new line before first line..

```
Address "ISREDIT"
VAR = 'TEST DATA'
"LINE_BEFORE .ZFIRST = (VAR)"
```

But this doesn't insert line when there is no line in the PDS.. Is there a command to insert line in blank PS file by Rexx macro

Answer (score 0):

Use the LINE_AFTER command with 0 as line number:
"LINE_AFTER 0 = (VAR)"